# Accuracy of a sklearn model too good for a realistic problem

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I tried to develop a sklearn model to predict the result of some matches (win or lose), expecting a really low accuracy as the data was real and the problem really difficult. I finished the project and the accuracy of my models waw too high to be true or even possible (reaching 0.993 on the best model) and of course I am doing something wrong.

The processes I used was the following:

1. Load the data
2. Encode the X data using different types of categorical encoders
3. Split into test and train (test_size=0.5) using a random state
4. List item
5. Fit different models with train data (RandomForestClassifier, GaussianNB, DecisionTreeClassifier and KNeighborsClassifier)
6. Predict test data generating the accuracy
7. Apply metrics for the model with best accuracy

At my dataset I have a enormous number of columns generated with One Hot Encoding, so this method was out of mind, and I decided to look for different modes, the ones that suited to my case were specially TargetEncoder, LeaveOneOutEncoder and WOEEncoder.

**Common mistakes that can "bypass" the accuracy metric and I've tried to fix:**

- Dataset with low number of rows: **my dataset has a considerable amount of data (6098 rows x 13 columns)**
- Information at X columns that are correlated with Y (Data leakage): **none of the columns has direct correlation with the result**
- Classes are imbalanced: **dataset has 3112 positive samples and 2986 negative samples**
- Duplicate data: **none of the samples in the training set exist in the test set**

The problem could be probably in the code

```
# ...
# Load the dataset
# ...

# Used different encoders, using LeaveOneOutEncoder for example
lou_enc = LeaveOneOutEncoder(cols=columnsToEncode)
lou_X = lou_enc.fit_transform(X, Y)

scaler = StandardScaler()
X_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X)
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X_scaled, Y, test_size=0.5, random_state=42)

# Used different encoders, using RandomForestClassifier for example
model = RandomForestClassifier()
model.fit(X_train, Y_train)
predicts = model.predict(X_test)
accuracyScore = accuracy_score(Y_test, predicts)
print(accuracyScore)
```

Metrics I got from the best accuracy model using different encoders
[image: metrics]

Comment: **To avoid leakage, do the train/test(/holdout) split before you do any encoding.** 70/30 split is fine, you don't need 50/50. Here's a useful Kaggle comparison [11 Categorical Encoders and Benchmark](https://www.kaggle.com/code/subinium/11-categorical-encoders-and-benchmark/notebook)

Comment: Instead of saying *"13 columns... gave an enormous number of columns generated with One Hot Encoding"*, show us how many unique categorical levels each categorical had. Also show use the feature importance for each categorical, according to RF (after you fix the split). It is perfectly possible both to skip low/zero-information features, and to merge less-frequent categorical labels to keep cardinality down (e.g. only assign distinct levels to say the most common 95%). Then, generate models based only on the top-2, top-3, top-F most important categoricals. Measure your accuracy as F increases.

Comment: Actually, cite us the dataset and link to it in the code, to make this reproducible. If you're allowed to.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Comment: BTW, why bothering to build `lou_X` if you were not to use it?

Comment: erm, if those encodings aren't used, then presumably the model build would fail from having categorical data?

Answer (score 1):

There is information being leaked from the test set to the train set, because you fit your scaler using the entire data. Try to split the data first, then fit the scaler using only the training data and only then transform both the train and test data, as follows:

```
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.5, random_state=42)
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(X_train)
X_train_scaled = scaler.transform(X_train)
X_test_scaled = scaler.transform(X_test)

model = RandomForestClassifier()
model.fit(X_train_scaled, Y_train)
predicts = model.predict(X_test_scaled)
accuracyScore = accuracy_score(Y_test, predicts)
```

Comment: The scaler leaks some information, but the _target encoders_ leak "more".

Comment: @BenReiniger Yes, same applies there of course; but the encoded data is not used in the provided example.

Comment: @BenReiniger it's true, but, as correctly noticed, the encoded targets seem not to be used in OP's code.